# JWT getPrincipal error , reference to Authentication is ambiguous

Tags: java, spring, security

I am using spring boot to do a JWT security to my app, when I try to generate a token I faced an error with the followed msg. The error in the `getPrincipal()` method:

```
java: reference to Authentication is ambiguous
  both enum org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.ciphers.Authentication in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.ciphers and interface org.springframework.security.core.Authentication in org.springframework.security.core match
```

and the code:

```
package com.accessjobs.pjp.security;

import com.accessjobs.pjp.domain.User;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.ciphers.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;  // **here is the error** 

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.accessjobs.pjp.security.SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME;
import static com.accessjobs.pjp.security.SecurityConstants.SECRET;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    //Generate the token

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();  //  ** and the error on this method **
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME);

        String userId = Long.toString(user.getId());

        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("id", (Long.toString(user.getId())));
        claims.put("username", user.getEmail());
        claims.put("fullName", user.getFullName());

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userId)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();
    }

    //Validate the token

    //Get user Id from token
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that Java can't resolve which Authentication definition to use, since you are importing two. The one you need is
`org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`, so simply delete the other import.

Comment: that's works fine! thank u .
i was thinking that the problem in the dependencies or in the tomcat